# Use for [$i] variable to create csv columns - Powershell

Tags: powershell, xml, csv

I am trying to grab information from the connectionstrings.config file and populate it to a CSV. I have the following script so far:

```
$Filename = "C:\new.config"
[xml]$config = Get-Content $fileName

$CSCount = $config.connectionStrings.add.connectionString.count

[array]$CS = $config.connectionStrings.add.connectionString
$CScount = $CS.count
$CSCount
for($i=0; $i -lt $CScount; $i++)
{
    New-Variable -Name "CS$i" -Value $CS[$i]
    New-Variable -Name "Password$i" -value ($CS[$i].Split(';') | 
    ConvertFrom-StringData).'Password'
}


$table=@"
foreach ($C in $CSCount) { connectionstring[$i] }
$Password[$i]
"@
#export to a csv file
$table | Set-Content $home\desktop\test.csv
```

The part where I am stuck and not sure what to do is how to use the for [$i] variable to create different CSV columns using the data located in the [$i] variable. So, I am checking how many connectionstrings does my file has and then use this array # to generate variables. Then, I went to populate these variable in different columns in Powershell. So, array[0] would have Password[0]. I thought of using foreach loop, but no luck.

Please help or suggest. Your help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create the CSV manually, PowerShell has the `ConvertTo-CSV` and `Export-Csv` cmdlets to do it for you!

If I understand your code the example should be as simple as:

```
$Filename = "C:\new.config"
[xml]$config = Get-Content $fileName
$config.connectionStrings | Export-Csv -Path $home\desktop\test.csv
```